# Abelianization and analysis of Fundamental Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

I am working through Hatcher on my own, and currently doing problem $9$ on $p53$. This problem brings up the strategy of abelianization of groups to solve problems of fundamental groups and retractions, a concept Hatcher never explains.

While I can easily see how an abelianized group is defined, it leaves many important questions unanswered (like what properties of groups are invariant under abelianization? What properties of maps are preserved? How to use abelianization in doing proofs at this level? etc.)

So, my question is: where I can go, or can someone provide such info in a fairly concise form for a "beginner" working at this level?